# Workaround for creating a sorted list of dictionaries, without the sorted() function

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

You apparently can't sort a dictionary **without using the sorted() function**.
So, is there a workaround to that? (The reason I don't use the sorted() function is that this is for a specific school project.)

In the list of dictionaries, each dictionary contains keys like "name", "price" and many more.

Small example dictionary list:

```
games = [
    {"name":"counterstrike", "price":15, "rating":98},
    {"name":"teamfortress2", "price":0, "rating":95},
    {"name":"half-life", "price":9, "rating":99}
]
```

I need to sort it on, for example, the highest price, but then still be able to access all the other keys/values.
The furthest I got to that was so that it took all the names, and sorted that using merge sort. But then I only had the "name" of it, and not the "price" etc.

So, can I maybe sort a dictionary by "price" by making a list/tuple out of it or something, sort that using an algorithm (quicksort? merge sort?), then put it back as a list of the now sorted dictionaries?

Comment: You have to implement the sorted function yourself, and games is a list of dictionaries

Comment: Correct, currently I am using merge sort. It works, but I don't know and can't find how to use it with dictionaries, which probably requires a different way, but I don't know that. Hence the question.

Comment: A list of dictionaries is a very eccentric way to store a collection of items with the same keys. You are practically reinventing data classes. So why not use a class, create a list of three objects of the same class, and then sort that list by the desired key?

Comment: If you've already implemented sorting by name, it should be very trivial to change the code so that you're comparing prices instead.  Unfortunately, you did not include your code, so it's not possible to actually point out the one or two lines of code that need to be updated, but I'm guessing you could literally do a find+replace `['name']` -> `['price']` and it'll work.

Comment: The actual list of dictionaries I am using is from a json with about 27000 steam games. 
@Noah That's an interesting idea, how would I go about going from a json list of dicts to classes though?
@ Samwise When I said I sorted it on name, I meant that I now have a list with names, but I need to be able to still access all the other keys, not only the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could decorate each game with the desired key and a tie-breaker, then sort and finally undecorate.

Sort by name:

```
decorated = [(g['name'], i, g) for i, g in enumerate(games)]
mysort(decorated)
games = [d[2] for d in decorated]
```

Sort by price (highest to lowest)

```
decorated = [(-g['price'], i, g) for i, g in enumerate(games)]
mysort(decorated)
games = [d[2] for d in decorated]
```

The tie-breaker is needed to avoid the dictionaries getting compared, which isn't allowed (would cause an error). I use the original index as tie-breaker, which additionally makes the sorting stable, regardless of sorting algorithm.

Comment: Hi, thanks you so much for your help! This is the first way I have found that does exactly what I need. Again, my thanks.